# How to load a graph in which nodes' ids are String in JUNG

Tags: graph-algorithm, jung

I have a graph in which nodes have string ids, not integer. That is the graph file is like below:

```
 *Vertices 4
 *edges
 A B
 B C
 D A
```

I use a `PajekNetReader` to load the graph from the file and it gives me an error saying "the ids must be integer". How can I load a graph with string lds in JUNG?

Answer (score 0):

The Pajek format that JUNG supports requires the vertex ids to be integers.  You can give them labels, however: see
http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/PajekNetReader.html
for details on the format.

Other options include using a different format and writing your own parser.